# Event delegation after removing class

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-delegation

I have a button

```
<button data-button='next' class="disabled">next</button>
```

I remove the disabled class to activate but the event does not work

```
   $("[data-button='next']:not(.disabled)").on('click', document, function(){
```

How can I get this working

Comment: Your delegation looks backwards to me. Can you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 3):

Which is not the right syntax for [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), update it as follows.

```
// provide any selector which is parent of the dynamic element
//--\/-- and present when handler is attaching
$(document).on('click', "[data-button='next']:not(.disabled)", function(){
   //  --------------------^^^^^---- provide the selector of corresponding  dynamic element
   // code here
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', "[data-button='next']:not(.disabled)", function() {
  console.log('clicked');
});

$("[data-button='next']").removeClass('disabled')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-button='next' class="disabled">next</button>
```